# show data in php web

Tags: php

I use `bigint(10)` to save a format date in phpMyAdmin. But I can't format it with d/m/Y in my website.

I use the following code:

```
<?php $sqldate = strtotime($row['ngaysinh']);echo date('d/m/y',$sqldate); ?>
```

Comment: Can you start by showing an example value from your table?

Comment: 14  Mao  30/11/99
15  Tram  30/11/99
16  Meo  12/12/10

Comment: these can't be values coming from a BIGINT field, can they? Can you show an example value of `ngaysingh`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a UNIX time stamp to store the date.  As such using `strtotime()` with an integer will return -1 (it's not a date string) and so what you are actually doing is:

```
echo date('d/m/y',-1);
```

which doesn't output anything.  Instead, use the following code:

```
echo date('d/m/y',$row['ngaysinh']);
```

Comment: oh, I'm sorry but i can't, Although i used code
<?php echo date('d/m/y',$row['ngaysinh']);?>
i show follow: 01/01/1970 and replay 01/01/1970

Comment: what do you get out put if you echo $row['ngaysinh'] ?

Comment: @Vuong please show some of the *original database data* you are using.

Comment: i think if used data(string $fomat[,int $timestamp]) will be than. but i don't know use "timestamp". Please!help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Vuong - the $timestamp is a unix timestamp which, by the looks of what you said in the original questions is what is stored in the table.  Can you provide a sample of the data you are trying to use so we can check?